# Ошибка компиляции Collections.synchronizedList: synchronizedList (java.util.List<T>) in Collections cannot be applied to java.util.ArrayLis

Tags: java

Пишу клиент — серверное приложение. Для учета подключившихся клиентов хочу использовать ArrayList. Один из вариантов синхронизации ArrayList найденных мною в интернете это Collections.synchronizedList.
Но при попытке использования следующего кода:

```
private ArrayList <Connection> listOfClients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Connection>());
```

Подчеркивает красным new ArrayList():

> synchronizedList (java.util.List) in Collections cannot be applied
>   to (java.util.ArrayList)
>   reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List conforms to ArrayList

В чем проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468187/collections-synchronizedlist-and-synchronized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) возвращает `List`, а не `ArrayList` о чем и говорит ошибка. Используйте `List`:

```
private List<Connection> listOfClients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Connection>());
```

Comment: Написал так как Вы указали. Теперь в самом начале после List подчеркивает <Connection> (Type 'java.awt.List' does not have type parameter). А  new ArrayList<Connection>() тоже подчеркивает и пишет (synchronizedList (java.util.List<T>) in Collections cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList<WIWServer.Connection>)
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to List

Comment: @МаксимБродский указывайте сообщение об ошибке, что и где подчеркивает мне отсюда невидно.

Comment: Странно. Создал абсолютно новый тестовый класс. Написал все тоже самое там же. Работает..... Раскоментил в рабочем классе эту же строку - уже не подчеркивает. Очень странно. Спасибо за посощь!

Comment: @МаксимБродский видимо что-то в настройках IDE. В таких случаях может помочь чистая сборка (Clean & Build)